# how to save to MYSQL in Spring boot with decimals if I save 10,000.00 it will be saved as 10 in MySQL. (Save only the numbers in front of comma.)

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

[Data I enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O80A2.png)
[Data that get Saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z721O.png)[Sevice Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvwS9.png)

I tried to save without the decimals and display it with the decimal it did not work. Thinking of saving the same value in a new textbox and saving it while making the new text box without comma. I think the comma is the problem hear and the data type I have chosen is double.

Comment: I don't see any Javascript here. Or Java. Or SQL.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, mysql will not recognize the comma as part of a number.  If you have the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES sql_mode enabled (which is the default in newer versions), you will get an error when you insert or update to a numeric field with such a value.  Without STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, you will only receive a warning, and the non-numeric portion will be discarded, leaving just `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you code a GUI yourself? If yes, then you are sending wrong type to your backend. If your GUI written in javascript and you are entering numbers with comma dont send the `value` of input directly, instead send `Number(value.replace("," , ""))`. And also check the field is not in type Long or Integer in Spring Boot. You should use Float or Double type in backend for floating numbers.

Comment: 'String[] qty2 = requisitionDto2.getQty2() == null ? null : requisitionDto2.getQty2().split(",");'